# decltype(function) as class member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++11, linker-errors, decltype

I have:

```
int foo(int x) { return x+1; }

struct Bar {
  decltype(foo) operator();
};

int main() {
  Bar bar;
  printf("%d\n",bar(6));
}
```

which results in the slightly startling compiler error message (g++ 4.6.1):

```
error: declaration of 'operator()' as non-function
```

When changing the member name to

```
  decltype(foo) blubb;
```

and using it results in a linker error:

```
undefined reference to `Bar::blubb(int)'
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Do you really want the type of the function, or instead the functions return type (which you could get by "simulating" a call like `decltype(foo(0))`)

Comment: I would say gcc has just not yet implemented it. It works fine in clang.

Comment: @phresnel: looking at how he invokes it (`bar(6)`) I would assume he wants the function. However I wonder if the linker error is a complaint (it is expected when not defining the function), or just to show that it created the function just fine.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Seeing how he buts the call to `Bar::operator()` to the `%d` format specifier, I would assume he means the function return type, not the function type.

Comment: PlasmaHH is right. I do mean the function, not the return type. I also  would like to note that `decltype(foo) blubb;` IMHO creates an alias name for the function, and that the linker should be able to link such constructs (with help from the compiler)... but you may prove me wrong.

Comment: @smilingthax: you misundestood what decltype does. It will just evaluate to a type, not more. The definition of blubb is in no way tied to the definition of foo. This might be clearer when writing it like `typedef decltype(foo) x; x blubb;`. you can now alternatively typedef x to be explicitly the function type, which will not in any way change what blubb is. you still need to define it.

Comment: @smilingthax: Okay. However, `decltype(foo) blubb` would [imo] create a pointer to a function of foo's signature. You would have to assign foo to it, too (`decltype(foo) blubb = foo;`).

Comment: No, it's not a pointer! I even can't do `typedef int ()(int) x;`

Comment: @phresnel: decltype(foo) is the type of the function, while decltype(&foo) is the pointer-to-function type for it. One can see that the compiler really created a function by the linker error. But I can't find a syntax that will allow to define the function this way...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Correct, neither could I... Actually the deeper issue then is, whether the function implementation is a property of the type or it's value. The only thing close is the forbidden `decltype([](int x){return x+1;})`.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Oh yeah, it's too long since I fiddled with function pointers.

Comment: @smilingthax: (Plasma pointed this out) `operator();` is not correct either, `operator()` tells the compiler `here comes a function call operator`, after that you have to tell him the parameters: `operator() (int arg1, float arg2)`, for example

Comment: @PlasmaHH: You can actually add `int Bar::blubb(int x) { return x+2; }` in the second case to make it link+work. So the first case clearly looks like a compiler problem with g++ -- your answer is actually the best one, please add it as such so I can actually accept it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want to "copy" the signature of another function to create a function with the same signature. Since `decltype(foo)` is indeed the type of the function (and not a pointer to that function, which would be `decltype(&foo)` and would lead to a pointer declaration), you can use it to declare a function with the same signature as another function.

As indicated by the linker error:

```
undefined reference to `Bar::blubb(int)'
```

this will already work fine with your compiler. However it seems that gcc did not yet fully implement this part of the standard, as it will not accept the syntax for the same thing with a function call operator. Clang btw. will happily accept it and the link then errors out with

```
undefined reference to `Bar::operator()(int)'
```

Your question about why that linker error exists indicates a misunderstanding of what decltype really does.

It will just evaluate to a type, not more. The definition of `blubb` is in no way tied to the definition of `foo`. This might be clearer when writing it like

```
typedef decltype(foo) x; 
x blubb;
```

You can now alternatively typedef x to be explicitly the function type, which will not in any way change what blubb is. You still need to define it. And since there is no syntax to define it using decltype, you explicitly have to write it as

```
int Bar::operator()(int) {
...
}
```

which will likely and unfortunately defeat the purpose/benefit of using decltype for the declaration, as it will not allow you to automatically "copy" a signature.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess based on observing your usage of printf here:

```
printf("%d\n",bar(6));
```

This lets me assume you really want the *return type* of the function, not the type of the function. If so, then you use `decltype` wrong. You get the return type of the function by "simulating" the usage of the function, i.e.

```
decltype(foo(0)) operator() (int);
```

should be the right thing for you. Otherwise, if that was not your attention, you are skating on thin ice by giving a function type (and not function return type) to the `%d` specifier.

Generally, the meaning of `decltype` is: `decltype(@)` gives the static type of the expression `@`.

Comment: Given that idea, your solution would need to be (also pickung up the usage pattern): `decltype(foo(0)) operator()(int);`

Comment: I'm well aware of the 'usual' pattern. This is not what I meant, see my first comment above. Still, your answer is probably what most users actually want.

Comment: @smilingthax: Oh I didn't want to lecture you. That was also for public's sake ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
I just used it here to capture whatever gobbledygook `std::bind` was going to give me:

```
class RiceFadingModel::Impl
{
public:
  Impl(double K, double A)
  : //...
    _M_re{system_now()},
    _M_rd{_M_nu, _M_sigma},
    _M_gen{std::bind(_M_rd, _M_re)}
  { }


private:

//...

  std::default_random_engine _M_re;
  ///  The underlying Rice distribution.
  __gnu_cxx::__rice_distribution<double> _M_rd;
  ///  The variate generator built from the pseudo-random number engine and the Rice distribution.
  decltype(std::bind(_M_rd, _M_re)) _M_gen;
};
```

This works like a charm on gcc-4.7.  Now that I think about it I built it on mingw with gcc-4.5 too.